# Can I get this motor to run AC?

Tags: motor, ac, generator, power-generation

[image]

My daughter has a project coming up for school. How can we use the turn table motor as a generator to power a shaded pole fan motor?

Comment: What does "get a...motor to power a...motor" mean? Do you mean to couple the shafts of the two motors so that one delivers _mechanical_ power to the other? Do you mean to connect wires so that one delivers _electrical_ power to the other? Do you mean something else?

Comment: So I have a little motor that came out of a microwave. I would like to wire that to a small fan motor. I want to be able to crank the microwave motor to produce the power needed to power the fan.

Comment: This sounds like a science project. Her doing some research on generators and how they work would help. I would suggest she write her hypothesis first and what she expects the results to be. Then put the system together documenting it. Then testing it and documenting the results and what she learned. I have judged Science fair projects for many years at the local, district and state levels. Some of the best and many were winners are the ones that failed. In real life most experiments fail, why when they work the experimenting stops!

Comment: As part of that, get a multimeter, set it to measure AC volts, and connect it to the turntable motor.  Spin it, and see if it generates any electricity.  Some motors will not generate electricity at all, we're unsure if that motor falls into the category.  If you have photos, that could help.

Comment: I do have a photo just don’t know how to up load it here. But when I crank the turntable motor I am getting 120 to 140v

Comment: This will be remarkably easier if you drop the existing motors and just buy a couple (cheap) hobby DC motors.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

That microwave turntable motor produces 120V on its terminals when you turn it only *slightly*. As the gearbox ratio is that high. But you can also turn it rather fast and then it has easily more than 1kV on its terminals, and its inertia makes it a pretty dangerous thing that may not linger around on an engineer's workbench for kids to play with.

Don't use such a thing in any device that isn't fool-proofed. With actual fools please.

(Also, the shaded pole motor likely needs more than the four watts that the turntable motor may provide.)